# Excel 2007: what happened to the Auto Expand Selection tool?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Older versions of Excel had a icon that would expand the selection to include any non-empty cells in all directions. It was an X shape with four arrowheads. You can still write VBA code to do this, but I really miss this tool. Did they just drop it from Excel 2007?

In older versions you had to go get it from the Customize menu because it wasn't on any toolbar by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the button to the quick access toolbar. Select More Commands in the Customize dialog. Then in the 'Choose commands from:' dropdown select 'Commands not in the ribbon' and it is called 'Select current region' (listed alphabetically). Then click add.

Ctrl+Shift+* will do the trick if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what guitarthrower said, it isn't a bad idea to lose the ribbon altogether. I threw it out after about an hour, and haven't missed it in 2 years.

Create your own sections in the quick access toolbar with buttons you need regularly. Believe me, it won't be many (mine after 2 years only has 16! buttons - I memorize key combos alot).

You'll get faster and more proficient that way.

Comment: Nope, I don't believe you.  I am using the Ribbon for most everything.